# How to close conversation from the webhook in @assistant/conversation

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, actions-builder

I want to close the conversation after the media started playing in @assistant/conversation. As I am doing here

```
app.intent("media", conv => {
    conv.ask(`Playing your Radio`);
    conv.ask(
        new MediaObject({
            url: ""
        })
    );
    return conv.close(new Suggestions(`exit`));
});
```

Comment: You cant close a conversation using a Suggestion. Suggestions are chips that show at the bottom of a conversation and are ment to continue the conversation forward.

Answer (score 0):

As Jordi had mentioned, suggestion chips cannot be used to close a conversation. Additionally, the syntax of the `@assistant/conversation` is different from `actions-on-google`. As you're using the tag `dialogflow-es-fulfillment` but also `actions-builder`, I really don't know which answer you want. As such, I'm going to put two answers depending on which you're using.

### Dialogflow

If you are using Dialogflow, you are pretty much set. You should switch to using `actions-on-google` and instantiate the dialogflow constant.

```js
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google')
const app = dialogflow()
```

### Actions Builder

The syntax of the `@assistant/conversation` lib is different. Some method names are different. Additionally, you will need to go through Actions Builder to canonically close the conversation.

In your scene, you will need to transition the scene to **End Conversation** to close, rather than specifying it as part of your response. Still, your end transition should not have suggestion chips.

[image]

You will need to refactor your webhook:

```js
const {conversation} = require('@assistant/conversation')
const app = conversation()

app.handle("media", conv => {
    conv.add(`Playing your Radio`);
    conv.add(
        new MediaObject({
            url: ""
        })
    );
    conv.add(new Suggestions(`exit`));
});
```

Comment: When I am closing conversation by End Conversation it is also closing the audio.

Comment: Yes, that is intentional. If you don't want the music to end, you should not close the conversation.

Comment: If I don't close the conversation then 'stop', 'pause' throwing an error because I am playing the live stream(radio), and with the live stream I am getting the 'Media_Status' undefined. Could you please help how to make 'stop', 'pause' work with the live stream? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you are trying to have a media control and after that to end the conversation, you should refer to the doc (https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-media) to check the available events as you have the chance to control each one for the media playback.

For example

```
// Media status
app.handle('media_status', (conv) => {
  const mediaStatus = conv.intent.params.MEDIA_STATUS.resolved;
  switch(mediaStatus) {
    case 'FINISHED':
      conv.add('Media has finished playing.');
      break;
    case 'FAILED':
      conv.add('Media has failed.');
      break;
    case 'PAUSED' || 'STOPPED':
      if (conv.request.context) {
        // Persist the media progress value
        const progress = conv.request.context.media.progress;
      }
      // Acknowledge pause/stop
      conv.add(new Media({
        mediaType: 'MEDIA_STATUS_ACK'
        }));
      break;
    default:
      conv.add('Unknown media status received.');
  }
});
```

Once you get the **FINISHED** status you can offer the suggestion chip to **exit** the conversation.

Comment: It only works with the media that have defined end time but when you play a live audio stream you will not get media status in the response

Comment: Sure! You are right... I didn´t notice that you need a radio player.